# Starting a mono-service with systemd

Tags: systemd, mono

I read a lot about systemd recently but i can't figure it out how to run my `mono-service` via systemd.

Below is my current systemd daemon configuration:

```
root@LNXOSESTNL:/opt/omnius-statusdaemon# cat /etc/systemd/system/omnius-statusdaemon.service 
[Unit]
Description="Omnius StatusDaemon"
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=omnius-statusdaemon
Group=omnius-statusdaemon
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono-service -d:/opt/omnius-statusdaemon /opt/omnius-statusdaemon/Dynacommerce.StatusQueueService.exe
PIDFile=/tmp/omnius-statusdaemon.pid
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When i run above exec script directly all is working fine and my `mono-service` is running. However via systemd the output is below:

```
root@LNXOSESTNL:/opt/omnius-statusdaemon# systemctl status omnius-statusdaemon.service
● omnius-statusdaemon.service - "Omnius StatusDaemon"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/omnius-statusdaemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2018-03-17 11:26:38 CET; 2s ago
  Process: 11099 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono-service -d:/opt/omnius-statusdaemon /opt/omnius-statusdaemon/Dynacommerce.StatusQueueService.exe (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11099 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 17 11:26:38 LNXOSESTNL systemd[1]: Started "Omnius StatusDaemon".
```

Hope that someone can help me guide to the right direction.

Comment: Put your `PIDFile` to `/var/run/`, I think it could help.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev tried that too before but it doesnt make any diff. Put it in /tmp to ensure that there is atleast no permission issue at all for now

Comment: Ok, so PIDFile exist and contains actual PID?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev no PID file created

Comment: So that's why systemd think that service dead.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev ok seems like it cant write to /var/run so think thats the main issue here

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemD think that service dead because there is no PID file on expected path. This pid file should be created by your service, systemd just check, it not create this file. If you don't want create this file in your service, may be you could create it with small shell script in section `ExecStartPost=`.